# What provides the fastest membership lookup in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Why do we have to avoid membership lookup using `Contains()` on any native container within lambda expressions?

Comment: With the exception of HashSet<T>, collections are not optimized for membership lookup. Therefore, using Contains()
inside a lambda means it will have to loop over the entire collection to find the membership status. This makes the
query slower.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you explain it by example?

Comment: What difference does a lambda expression make?

Comment: The Enumerable.Contains() extension method takes an IEnumerable.  That's not great, only way to do lookup is to enumerate all elements in the collection.  So O(n) cost.  Best way to do it is with HashSet or Dictionary, amortized O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider the following:

```
var source = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var matches = new[] { 12, 2, 19, 8, 40, 12, 123, 121, 1212, 122334, 2, 102, 10, 29 };
foreach (var item in source.Where(i => matches.Contains(i)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Now, let's consider how many items in `matches` `i` has to be compared with before we know whether to write it out or not:

```
1: 14
2: 2
3: 14
5: 14
6: 14
7: 14
8: 4
9: 14
10: 13
```

While we sometimes get the answer quite quickly, we generally don't especially if the answer is that we shouldn't, so we've got 103 comparisons to process 10 items. We also waste time comparing values we've already checked (the fact that `2` is in `matches` twice).

We're doing an `O(m)` operation n times so the algorithm is `O(nm)`.

We can do better with:

```
var source = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var matches = new HashSet<int> { 12, 2, 19, 8, 40, 12, 123, 121, 1212, 122334, 2, 102, 10, 29 };
foreach (var item in source.Where(i => matches.Contains(i)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Because `Contains` on a hash-set is `O(1)` the algorithm overall is `O(n)`, which is about as good as it can be.

Some important things to note though are:

1. If the above being done on a database then whatever type `matches` was it would be turned into a `CONTAINS` part of the `WHERE` clause in the SQL produced, so it doesn't matter (`CONTAINS` is still much slower than `=` up to a certain number of chained `=` but the factors in play are different).
2. With relatively small sets of matches it's cheaper to take the `O(n)` cost of the `Contains` than the constant costs of creating and searching the hash-set. (The above examples will probably take about the same time to run).

So it's not something to never do, but something where you should be aware of the costs and how they are affected by the source data and the way they are run, and how to improve performance when the cost is particularly high.

It's also not particularly significant that we're using lambdas, except that lambdas letting us write some code quickly lets us write some code with hidden inefficiencies quickly, whereas if we had to write two separate `foreach` loops the fact that the algorithm is `O(nm)` would be more obvious.